# error Command failed with exit code 1. when i close the yarn react program?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, yarnpkg

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/91LsA.png)

When i close the yarn react program, it gives the error

- VITE v4.4.2  ready in 1427 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.*

i'm using

- react
- vite
- typescript
- tailwind

how can i solve it?

i deleted node_module and yarn-lock and  installed yarn again it is not working